# Starting a Redis cluster with an RDB file

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, redis-cluster

I'm trying to create a Redis cluster using an RDB file taken from a single-instance Redis server. Here is what I've tried:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
for i in 6000 6001 6002 6003
do
  redis-server --port $i --cluster-config-file "node-$i.cconf" --cluster-enabled yes --dir "$(pwd)" --dbfilename dump.rdb &
done
```

That script starts up 4 Redis processes that are cluster enabled. It also initializes each node with the dump file.

Then I run `redis-trib.rb` so that the 4 nodes can find each other:

```
redis-trib.rb create 127.0.0.1:6000 127.0.0.1:6001 127.0.0.1:6002 127.0.0.1:6003
```

I get the following error:

```
>>> Creating cluster
[ERR] Node 127.0.0.1:6060 is not empty. Either the node already knows other nodes (check with CLUSTER NODES) or contains some key in database 0.
```

I've also tried a variant where only the first node/process is initialized with the RDB file and the others are empty. I can join the 3 empty nodes into a cluster but not the one that's pre-populated with data.

What is the correct way to import a pre-existing RDB file into a Redis cluster?

In case this is an "[X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)" this is why I'm doing this:

I'm working on a migration from a single-instance Redis server to an Elasticache Redis Cluster (cluster mode enabled). Elasticache can easily import an RDB file on cluster startup if you upload it to S3. But it takes a long time for an Elasticache cluster to start. To reduce the feedback loop as I test my migration code, I'd like to be able to start a cluster locally also.

I've also tried using the [create-cluster](https://github.com/antirez/redis/tree/unstable/utils/create-cluster) utility, but that doesn't appear to have any options to pre-populate the cluster with data.

Comment: I believe you are looking for this? https://fnordig.de/2014/03/11/redis-cluster-with-pre-existing-data/

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes! That works! If you make it an answer I can award you the bounty. Thanks